# Cannot mount drive under ubuntu server 18.04

Tags: 18.04, mount, mdadm, fdisk, gdisk

I have upgraded my home server from ubuntu 12.04 to 18.04. The system holds 2 disks of 2.0TB in Raid 1. When I try to mount them on the 18.04 I get the following error.

mount -t ntfs /dev/md126 /mnt/media

I have also tried  mount -t ntfs-3g without success.

```
NTFS signature is missing.
Failed to mount '/dev/md126': Invalid argument
The device '/dev/md126' doesn't seem to have a valid NTFS.
Maybe the wrong device is used? Or the whole disk instead of a
partition (e.g. /dev/sda, not /dev/sda1)? Or the other way around?
```

The ouput from fdisk -l /dev/md126 is

```
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x000136a9

Device       Boot Start        End    Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/md126p1         63 3907023111 3907023049  1.8T  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT

Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.
```

And the output of gdisk -l is

```
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 1.0.3

Partition table scan:
  MBR: MBR only
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: not present


***************************************************************
Found invalid GPT and valid MBR; converting MBR to GPT format
in memory.
***************************************************************


Warning! Secondary partition table overlaps the last partition by
297 blocks!
You will need to delete this partition or resize it in another utility.
Disk /dev/md126: 3907022848 sectors, 1.8 TiB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512/4096 bytes
Disk identifier (GUID): DC6C901E-C3A5-43C1-8C9E-8E6397C5F145
Partition table holds up to 128 entries
Main partition table begins at sector 2 and ends at sector 33
First usable sector is 34, last usable sector is 3907022814
Partitions will be aligned on 8-sector boundaries
Total free space is 29 sectors (14.5 KiB)

Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
   1              63      3907023111   1.8 TiB     0700  Microsoft basic data
```

And finally when i check the mdadm --detail /dev/m126 i get the following result

```
/dev/md126:
         Container : /dev/md/imsm0, member 0
        Raid Level : raid1
        Array Size : 1953511424 (1863.01 GiB 2000.40 GB)
     Used Dev Size : 1953511424 (1863.01 GiB 2000.40 GB)
      Raid Devices : 2
     Total Devices : 2

             State : clean
    Active Devices : 2
   Working Devices : 2
    Failed Devices : 0
     Spare Devices : 0

Consistency Policy : resync


              UUID : 562a1dd0:13fa432c:bec8c322:89cbd43f
    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       1       8        0        0      active sync   /dev/sda
       0       8       16        1      active sync   /dev/sdb
```

When I switch back to the 12.04 (I've installed 18.04 on a new disk) everything works fine.

Does anyone have an idea what is going wrong?

When I try to mount the partition I get a similar error 
mount /dev/md126p1 -t ntfs-3g /mnt/media

```
Failed to read last sector (3907023047): Invalid argument
HINTS: Either the volume is a RAID/LDM but it wasn't setup yet,
   or it was not setup correctly (e.g. by not using mdadm --build ...),
   or a wrong device is tried to be mounted,
   or the partition table is corrupt (partition is smaller than NTFS),
   or the NTFS boot sector is corrupt (NTFS size is not valid).
Failed to mount '/dev/md126p1': Invalid argument
The device '/dev/md126p1' doesn't seem to have a valid NTFS.
Maybe the wrong device is used? Or the whole disk instead of a
partition (e.g. /dev/sda, not /dev/sda1)? Or the other way around?
```

Comment: In your first command you use `/dev/mda126` - typo?

Comment: @Jos that's a typo in my question, edited it.

Comment: No need to add *Solved* and solution to the question. Accepting an answer is enough to mark your question as Solved :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You attempt to mount the wrong device. You're trying to mount `/dev/mda126`, which is not the partition.

Replace `/dev/mda126` with `/dev/md126p1`.

Comment: Please update your question with exact command and exact error message.

Comment: And as a sidenote: this is a very strange configuration. You have a MD array, which by default is only accessible on Linux, with a file system that only has a complete toolset available for Windows...

Comment: I made this array a long time ago. I use the array as a samba share. Maybe it is a good idea to just backup the data and recreate the array then?

Comment: Thanks, I was indeed mounting the wrong device. As a addition to the solution I had to run ntfsfix /dev/md126p1. Marked your answer as solution.

Comment: As it is a device that can only be used on a Linux system, if possible, a Unix file system would be a better idea in my opinion. You have to weigh this against the cost of recreating the file system.